# Is my silver birch dead?

Tags: trees

I live in the UK, and have a silver birch in front of my house and a large branch fell off of it recently. (On the floor to the left of the tree. It used to be attached on the left of the tree where there's now a stub).

It still has greenish leaves on most of the branches, although autumn is setting in now, so they're starting to brown/fall.

Is it dead (or dying)?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not dead, but it might be on its way out. There is some evidence of die back at the top on the same side where the branch fell off, and I note also a longitudinal, rather wide crack in the main trunk. It looks quite old - Birch does not have as long a life span as many other trees, though they should last about 50/60 years if they are healthy.

Go out and lean hard against the trunk, or push it to see if it's stable; also examine the main trunk for signs of weeping or soggy areas, as well as checking just how far into the heartwood that crack goes. If the crack extends well into the tree, or you find other soft or weeping areas, I'd suggest consulting a good tree surgeon to come and inspect it for health and safety, with a view to removing it if necessary before other parts fall. Next time a branch falls off, there might be someone underneath it...you were lucky the good sized branch that fell off did not fall onto the fence and cause damage there.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Tree surgeon called out. Let's see what they say.

Answer (score 1):

Tree surgeon decided it was dead, here's the result.

Just in time for storm Arwen!

[image]